# MySQL compare name and address

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
name | last name | postal code | street+no
------------------------------------------
max  | tester    | 12345       | teststreet 1
mia  | tester    | 12345       | teststreet 1
frank| stein     | 54321       | streettest 2
```

and I want to show up my query result like this:

```
name   | last name | postal code | street+no
----------------------------------------------
family | tester    | 12345       | teststreet 1
frank  | stein     | 54321       | streettest 2
```

So it should test if there are **lastnames** with same **address** and `CONCAT` them into 1 row with *family* as **name**

I did this before, but it just shows me the table without first names, and i don't know how to compare them right...

```
SELECT DISTINCT `last name`,`postal code`, `street+no` 
  FROM `users` 
 ORDER BY `last name`
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty self explaining:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'family' ELSE name END AS name,
last_name,
postal_code,
street_no
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 
last_name,
postal_code,
street_no
```